# Checking Possible Nulls Linq Query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have for simplicity 2 tables:

```
Table1 has UserId Email
Table2 has UserId Score
```

I want to filter out all scores > 10. But, Table2 is not guaranteed to have any users in it. UserId is a PK and FK on Table2. UserId is a PK on table 1.

My issue is that I need to get all scores where they exist and then check them.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, what you've tried, or what problems you've had.

Comment: What The Skeet said; My wild guesses are just that - wild guesses. My main one is your table structure is wonky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Left Outer Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee908647#leftouterjoin)

```
var q =

    from user in Table1 

    join s in Table2 on user.UserId  equals score.UserId  into lscore

    from score in lscore.DefaultIfEmpty()

    where score == null || lscore.score < 10

    select new { userId = user.userid,  email = user.Email, Score = score == null ? 0 : lscore.score };
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I needed a left outer join. But, I didn't know how to do the checking part for the value.

Comment: Actually this query doesn't work. lscore doesn't have a score, perhaps you meant score. I am testing this now. Thanks again.